# Highlighting Table Rows does not work

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table a jquery script as given in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Hb28u/4/. There are four jQuery approaches for highlighting table rows. The last two approaches does not work, Why are they not working?  I am looking for an explanation in plain English.

HTML

```
<table id="table1">
<tr> <td>N</td><td>Y</td></tr>  
<tr class="y_n"><td>Q</td><td>N</td></tr>  
</table> 

 <br/><br/>

<table id="table2">
<tr> <td>N</td><td>Y</td></tr>  
<tr class="y_n"><td>Q</td><td>N</td></tr> 
</table> 

<br/><br/>

<table id="table3">
<tr> <td>N</td><td>Y</td></tr>  
<tr class="y_n"><td>Q</td><td>N</td></tr>  
</table> 

 <br/><br/>

<table id="table4">
<tr> <td>N</td><td>Y</td></tr>  
<tr class="y_n"><td>Q</td><td>N</td></tr>  
 </table> 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js">
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function()
{


//Apporach 1  - Highlight First Row

$('#table1 tr td:eq(0)').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'Orange');
}
});


//Apporach 2 -  - Highlight Second Row

$('#table2 tr td:gt(0)').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'Orange');
}
});


//Apporach 3 - Highlight Second Row

$('#table3 tr td:eq(1)').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'Orange');
}
});


//Apporach 4 Highlight All Rows

$('#table4 tr td)').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'Orange');
}
});

});
```

Comment: Approach 4 : '#table4 tr td)' would be '#table4 tr td'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it works [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hb28u/8/)

```
$('#table3 tr td:eq(3)').each(function() { // note that you search for td no. 3 and not 1
   if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
      $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'Orange');
   }
});


//Apporach 4 Highlight All Rows
$('#table4 tr td').each(function() { // note that in your example you have a ) at the end of the selector
    if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'Orange');
    }
});
```

Comment: That means td has continuous numbering?

Comment: the selector `#table3 tr td` returns you an array with all tds inside of selected tr, so each td has its own index in the order it has been found

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I find it to be a performance issue. I would go for adding a CSS Class for the required row in ASP.Net GridView in RowDataBound event. And select row based on css class.. $(#myTable tr.myclass') http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390200/how-do-i-specify-css-classes-for-specific-rows-in-a-gridview

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Apporach 3 - Highlight Second Row
$('#table3 tr:eq(1) td').each(function() { //second row
if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'Orange');
}
});


    //Apporach 4 Highlight All Rows
    $('#table4 tr td').each(function() { //here you had a unnescessary ')'
    if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'Orange');
    }
    });
```

hope you got it :)

Comment: No. The approach 3 that you mentioned is same as Approach 1. Approach 3 does not do its task - see http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Hb28u/12/