# How to remove row from datagrid in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid dgCompanies declare like this:

```
// bind the data to the datagrid
dgCompanies.PageSize = pageSize;
dgCompanies.DataSource = rdr;
```

Then I need to check the records inside this datagrid:

```
int j = 0;
foreach (DataGridItem item in dgCompanies.Items)
{
    HtmlGenericControl name = (HtmlGenericControl)item.Cells[j].FindControl("SpanTitle");   
    string drstring = name.InnerHtml.Trim();

    if (checkingfunction(drstring))
    {
       //do removing record from datagrid.
        I tried this:  item.Cells.Remove(item.Cells[j]); but the result still there, don't see anything removed!
    }

    j = j + 1;                    
 }

 dgCompanies.DataBind();
```

How could I remove that record from datagrid `dgCompanies` when if condition is satisfy ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and more natural to filter the datasource instead?

Comment: I don't think it is easy, pls refer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774851/how-remove-records-from-datagrid-in-asp-net-if-condition-satisfy

Comment: I tried: item.Cells.Remove(item.Cells[j]); but the result still there, don't see anything removed!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Andrei, it would be best to just not return that data.  Otherwise you're returning and churning through data that is unnecessary.  However, if in the context of you can't filter the data up front, I suppose you could add a css class "donotshow" to your rows (see [How do I specify CSS classes for specific rows in a GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390200/how-do-i-specify-css-classes-for-specific-rows-in-a-gridview)).

Then using jquery use

```
$('.donotshow').hide();
```

Again, in this regard, you are still returning all that HTML to the browser, so that will make your page size larger than necessary.  Additionally, using this method could screw up pagination if you using it (example, if it says "rows 1-10", but 5 rows are hidden, then that will look goofy).

Hope this helps

Comment: How do I "mark" that rows in codebehind when if condition is satisfy? then how to hide it ? Could you give example with codebehind and ascx file ?

Comment: I tried this: item.Cells[j].Visible = false; but I don't see any change either.

Comment: Do I need to make change at ascx file as well ?